# Traits and abstract methods override in Scala

Tags: scala, traits

I have a base abstract class (trait). It has an abstract method `foo()`. It is extended and implemented by several derived classes. I want to create a trait that can be mixed into the derived classes so that it implements `foo()` and then calls the derived class's `foo()`.

Something like:

```
trait Foo {
  def foo()
}

trait M extends Foo {
  override def foo() {
    println("M")
    super.foo()
  }
}

class FooImpl1 extends Foo {
  override def foo() {
    println("Impl")
  }
}

class FooImpl2 extends FooImpl1 with M
```

I tried self types and structural types, but I can't get it to work.

Answer (score 102, accepted):

You were very close. Add the abstract modifier to M.foo, and you have the 'Stackable Trait' pattern: http://www.artima.com/scalazine/articles/stackable_trait_pattern.html

```
trait Foo {
  def foo()
}

trait M extends Foo {
  abstract override def foo() {println("M"); super.foo()}
}

class FooImpl1 extends Foo {
  override def foo() {println("Impl")}
}

class FooImpl2 extends FooImpl1 with M
```

Comment: What if I don't have M? I'm trying to override the method from Foo in the class and have the same error.

Comment: What does `super.foo()` do when foo is unimplemented in the super class?

Comment: @lamin The trait `M` needs to be mixed in along with its super class or trait, and if that super class or trait doesn't have `foo` implemented, then it can't be overriden yet, and `super.foo()` won't get called.