# How do abstract override work in terms of Java code?

Tags: scala, traits

I found [a great explanation of how trait is compiled to Java code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7637752/using-scala-traits-with-implemented-methods-in-java), but I think it is missing an "abstract override" feature. What Java code is generated for this feature?

Comment: Also take a lookt at this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7637752/using-scala-traits-with-implemented-methods-in-java

Answer (score 6):

Here it comes:

- *[Traits and abstract methods override in Scala](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2038370)*
- *[Scala's Stackable Trait Pattern](http://www.artima.com/scalazine/articles/stackable_trait_pattern.html)*

It short, `abstract override def m()` allows to call `super.m()` from the method and this super call bounds dynamicaly in place of type creation, when a trait is mixing-in *after* all other types, for example

```
trait Printer {
  def print(msg: String)
}

trait Shouter extends Printer {
  abstract override def print(msg: String) { super.print(msg + "!") }
}

class ConsolePrinter extends Printer {
  def print(msg: String) { println(msg) }
}

val loudPrinter = new ConsolePrinter with Shouter

loudPrinter.print("Scala is great")
```

Here we are mixing-in Shouter later, after type linearisation it becomes 'Shouter extends ConsolePrinter', and a call to `super.print()` becomes`ConsolePrinter.print()` and it gives us:

```
Scala is great!
```

Google more for "stackable trait pattern", it's a great thing! :)

Agh... I forgot about Java :)

For a given example, we'll have Shouter.class - interface Shouter with methods:

```
  [0] Shouter$$super$print
  [1] print
```

Next, Shouter$class.class - concrete class named "Shouter$class" with static method `print(LShouter;Ljava/lang/String;)V` and the body:

```
 0 aload_0
 1 new #8 <scala/collection/mutable/StringBuilder>
 4 dup
 5 invokespecial #12 <scala/collection/mutable/StringBuilder.<init>>
 8 aload_1
 9 invokevirtual #16 <scala/collection/mutable/StringBuilder.append>
12 ldc #18 <!>
14 invokevirtual #16 <scala/collection/mutable/StringBuilder.append>
17 invokevirtual #22 <scala/collection/mutable/StringBuilder.toString>
20 invokeinterface #28 <Shouter.Shouter$$super$print> count 2
25 return
```

That is, calling method `Shouter$$super$print(String)` on passed instance.

Next, `$$anon$1.class` - concrete class named "$anon$1" - this is our `new ConsolePrinter with Shouter`. It implements interface Shouter, that is, have it methods implemented. And here:

```
print(Ljava/lang/String;)V

0 aload_0
1 aload_1
2 invokestatic #21 <Shouter$class.print>
5 return
```

`Shouter$$super$print(Ljava/lang/String;)V`:

```
0 aload_0
1 aload_1
2 invokespecial #11 <ConsolePrinter.print>
5 return
```

That is, in called `print()` we're calling `static Shouter$class.print()` which is an implementation from Shouter trait. That print adds `!` and calls Shouter$$super$print() on our object and we forward call to ConsolePrinter.

Here is it.